# A question on polynomials and functional equations.

Tags: polynomials

> If $P(x)$ is a cubic polynomial which satisfies
>
> - $(x-1) ^2$ is a factor of $P(x) +2 $ and
>     $(x+1) ^2$ is a factor of $P(x)-2$
>
> then what is the value of  $P(3)$ ?

Please give a general solution. And also a shorter way for MCQ's

Comment: **Hint:** The Extended Euclidean Algorithm says $\frac{2-x}{4}(x+1)^2+\frac{2+x}{4}(x-1)^2=1$

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail about this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By hypothesis, $$(x-1)^2g(x)-2=P(x)=(x+1)^2h(x)+2$$ for some  $h(x)=mx+a$ and $g(x)=mx+b$.

$$x=1 \implies -2=4h(1)+2$$ 
 $$x=-1\implies 2=4g(-1)-2$$

so  $h(1) = -1$ and $g(-1) = 1$. Thus $$-1=m+a\\1=-m+b$$ so $a+b=0$

Also $$P(0)=g(0)-2=h(0)+2 \implies b-2=a+2 \implies a-b=-4$$

Solving $a$ and $b$, we get $a=-2$ and $b=2$ and hence $m=1$

Thus $g(x)=x+2$ and $h(x)=x-2$ and hence $$P(x)=(x-1)^2(x+2)-2=(x+1)^2(x-2)+2=x^3-3x$$

So $P(3)=3^3-3^2$

Comment: Thanks I was stuck after writing in general form and had no idea how to find values of g(x) and h(x) thank you

Comment: @downvoter: Whats wrong?

Comment: This is better than my solution and you had my upvote, but assuming $P(x)$ to be monic is missing explanation. Otherwise, if $h(x) = mx+a$ and $g(x) = mx+b$, I would hope to see the explanation why $m = 1$.

Comment: @peterwhy: see my edit. Is it now ok?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR looks good, thanks!

Comment: @UT's: Are you understand whats going on this proof? which step you do not understand?

Comment: It's ok to not consider P(x) monic but why have you used same variable for m in g(x) and h(x) and why not h(x) = m1x+a and g(x) = m2x+b. Please explain the reason.

Comment: When I was solving the problem before asking here I took m1x+a and m2x+b and didn't found any reason why m1 = m2

Comment: The factor $(x-1)^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ are monic, so we need same constant $m$

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Can please explain me peterwhy's answer which involves differentiating. Maybe I could use it as a general way for similar type of questions in MCQ's. I just want to know how did peter figure turning points and equations in terms of coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2+Cx+D$. Then $P'(x) = 3Ax^2 + 2Bx + C$.

For the graph $y=P(x)$, $(1,-2)$ and $(-1, 2)$ are stationary points (and actually turning points).

$$\begin{align*}
-2 &= A+B+C+D\\
0 &= 3A + 2B+C\\
2 &= -A + B-C+D\\
0 &= 3A-2B+C
\end{align*}$$

Solve for $3^3A + 3^2B+3C + D$.

---

$(x-1)^2$ is a factor of $P(x)+2$, i.e. $x=1$ is a double (or higher-order) root of $P(x)+2$. So cubic polynomial $P(x)$ has a stationary point at $x=1$, and similarly another stationary point at $x=-1$.

I did not think a lot about it when I first answered, just scribbled a cubic curve in my head. But if you want a proof: let $P(x)+2 = (x-1)^2g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is a linear polynomial. Then by differentiating both sides,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac d{dx}(P(x)+2) &= \frac d{dx} \left[(x-1)^2g(x)\right]\\
P'(x) &= (x-1)^2g'(x) + g(x)\cdot 2(x-1)\\
&= (x-1)\left[(x-1)g'(x) + 2g(x)\right]\\
P'(1) &= 0
\end{align*}$$

i.e. $P(x) +2$ and therefore $P(x)$ have a stationary point at $x=1$.

Comment: $A=1, C=-3, B=D=0$

Comment: I appreciate your short answer with differentiation but how did you find the turning points and the equations in terms of A, B, C, D

Comment: @peterwhy: I like your solution can you please explain in more detail about why did you differentiate and how did you find turning points and how the relation between coefficients is established? Please explain in detail.

Comment: @UT's: A **turning point** is a point at which the derivative changes sign. If the function is differentiable, then a turning point is a stationary point 

  Here $P(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$  and by hypothesis $P(x)+2=(x-1)^2 \cdot h(x)$ and $P(x)-2=(x+1)^2 \cdot k(x)$ for some linear $h$ and $k$.

so $$P(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=(x-1)^2 \cdot h(x)-2=(x+1)^2 \cdot k(x)+2$$ and $$P'(x)=3Ax^2+2Bx+C=(x-1)^2 \cdot h'(x)+2h(x)(x-1)=(x+1)^2 k'(x)+2k(x)(x+1)$$ Now put $x=-1,1$ in $P'(x)$ to see , $P'(1)=0=P'(-1)$

Comment: @UT's: (continuation :) $$-2=P(1) \implies A+B+C+D=-2$$

$$0=P'(1) \implies 3A+2B+C=0$$

$$2=P(-1) \implies -A+B-C+D=2$$

$$0=P'(-1) \implies 3A-2B+C=0$$

Now solve this to find $P(3)=3^3A+3^2B+3C+D.$

Comment: @UT's I expanded my answer.

Comment: @peterwhy Thanks brother

Comment: Thanks to Chinnapparaj R also for explaination.

Comment: @peterwhy I think the y co ordinate of turning point is the remainder when we write P(x) as Dividend=Q*d + r am I right please let me know.